# Compute triangular matrix indices from "flat array" index?

Tags: algorithm, performance, pseudocode

Got a triangular matrix represented as a flat array

```
0 = [0, 0]
1 = [1, 0], 2 = [1, 1]
3 = [2, 0], 4 = [2, 1], 5 = [2, 2]
6 = [3, 0], 7 = [3, 1], 8 = [3, 2], 9 = [3, 3]
```

What is the quickest way to compute the index pair using the original index?
One way (naive brute force) to do it is counting like this:

```
void foo(uint n) {
    uint origN = n;
    uint i = 0;
    while(n > i) {
        n -= ++i;
    }
    cout << origN << " = " << "[" << i << ", " << n << "], ";
    if (i == n) {
       cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is there a way that is immediate and simple to implement?

Comment: This might benefit from a language specific tag.

Comment: It should be a very simple, plain algorithm in Pseudocode.

Comment: what is the output of this?

Comment: You can do a binary to find the largest n such that (x * (x + 1)) / 2 < n

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, yeah I was thinking the same thing. Was curious about the formula the answerers presented and how they got it.

Comment: @ergonaut , well, you get an index of a flat array that is representing a triangular matrix and the result is the cell in the triangular matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first number `n` in every row is `r*(r+1)/2` where `r` is the row number. Solving `n = r*(r+1)/2` equation you have this positive `r` root:

```
r = (sqrt(1+8*n)-1)/2
```

So to get the row number for arbitrary `n` you should just round down the result:

```
r = floor(sqrt(1+8*n)-1)/2
```

Now the column number can be found as difference between the `n` and the first number on the line:

```
c = n - r*(r+1)/2
```

Here's an example code in Java:

```
public static void foo(int n) {
    int r = (int) Math.floor((Math.sqrt(8 * n + 1) - 1) / 2);
    int c = n - r * (r + 1) / 2;
    System.out.println("n = " + n + "; r = " + r + "; c = " + c);
}
```

Comment: Forgot you can do this with Vieta's formula. haha :)

Answer (score 1):

For input `n`,answer can be found using this:

```
k = (int)(((int)(sqrt(8*n + 1)) - 1)/2)

l = (int)(n - (k * (k+1) /2 ))
```

Answer:

```
(k,l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option, probably not the best (just to show I've put thought into this):

It is a binary search over a monotonic increasing function:

```
void bar(uint n) {
    uint i = 1;
    while (n >= i * (i + 1) / 2) {
        i <<= 1;
    }
    i >>= 1;
    uint stepSize = i >> 1;
    while (stepSize) {
        uint tmp = i + stepSize;
        if (n >= tmp * (tmp + 1) / 2) {
            i = tmp;
        }
        stepSize >>= 1;
    }

    cout << n << " = " 
         << "[" << i << ", " << (n - i * (i + 1) / 2) << "], ";
    if (i == n - i * (i + 1) / 2) {
       cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```